# Is there any way to allow generate_otp_backup_codes using validate_and_consume_otp?

Tags: reactjs, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I am using device-two-factor gem for otp generation in rails.
I am using `generate_otp_backup_code` to a specific user for testing purpose which is generating otp successfully.
`validate_and_consume_otp` allows otp created via `generate_otp_secret` whereas `validate_and_consume_otp` dosen't allow the backup code otp to login.

Is there any way to allow `generate_otp_backup_codes` via `validate_and_consume_otp`?

```
tinfoil /devise-two-factor
gem 'devise-two-factor'
```

In `user.rb`

```
devise  :two_factor_authenticatable,
otp_secret_encryption_key:Rails.application.secrets.secret_key_base
devise :two_factor_backupable, otp_backup_code_length:     6,
            otp_number_of_backup_codes: 10
```

To generate backup codes:

```
codes = current_user.generate_otp_backup_codes!
current_user.save!
```